# "At the very beginning {or} middle {or} end"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

**a b c d e f g h i j k l m n.**

> 1. The letter "b" is not at the *very* beginning but at the beginning.
> 2. The letter "i" is not at the *very* middle but at the middle.
> 3. The letter "m" is not at the *very* end but at the end.

Am I right?

Comment: '_Towards_ the beginning' etc are usually used to show not being at the very beginning etc.

Comment: 2 doesn’t work. We don’t normally say that something is _at_ the middle, but _in_ the middle. Also, there doesn’t appear to be an i in the list at all (though I can’t tell in this font whether it’s an L or and uppercase i).

Comment: None are really "perfect", without the list in bold, I would have  interpreted the positions of these letters differently.

Comment: For a list, normally beginning and end denote first and last, so "toward" or "near" can be used. Normally middle implies some vague notion of middle, and "exactly the middle" clarifies the case where an exact middle matters.